# Why does SoftWar not ask me for the root password when installing the program

Tags: arch-linux, root

I am using Arch Linux

I have noticed that the software installs programs such as minetest or red alert without a root password

But why does this happen?

Interesting because when I uninstall it it asks me for the root password, but it does not ask for it during installation

Comment: Perhaps it is installed under the user you are currently running and deploys it under its home directory which does not need root privs, with the uninstall assuming you do need them, when it does not. Or, perhaps the install is using cached sudo privs, but the uninstall does not. Just check where the files are actually loaded.

Comment: I did not know how interesting .... the files were uploaded in the /usr/share path @Bib

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer
I got help from this question and answer

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=215993

I deleted the following file to fix it

`rm /usr/share/polkit-1/rules.d/org.freedesktop.packagekit.rules`

Comment: The article cited said "*Is your normal user a member of the wheel group? Check /usr/share/polkit-1/rules.d/org.freedesktop.packagekit.rules*". It did *not* say you should delete the file**!**

Comment: Sorry, I'm weak in English and use a translator

Because of this I could not understand the article properly @U. Windl